# How to configure pay load type router for type of list of different object?

Tags: spring-integration

There is a requirement where I've to return list of two different object based on certain conditions. 
I've configured payload-type-router as mentioned below, but it is throwing no-default-channel configured.

```
<int:payload-type-router input-channel="routingChannel">
  <int:mapping type="java.util.list&ltpkg.class1&gt" channel="Channel1" />
  <int:mapping type="java.util.list&ltpkg.class2&gt" channel="Channel2" />
```

If default channel is configured then it sends the message to default channel only irrespective of type.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payload type router does not currently support generic types because of type erasure - the payload class name (`java.util.List`) is compared to your configured String. We could probably do something to handle simple types like this by parsing the string, and perhaps more complex generic types using `ParameterizedTypeReference`s and Java configuration. But there's no such support today.

Feel free to open a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) and we'll consider it for a future enhancement.

Even if such support was there, your syntax is bad; `java.util.list` should be `java.util.List` and `&lt` should be `&lt;`.

Your strings will never match a payload type's class name (with erased generics); which is why all messages go to the default channel.

In the mean time, you can create a simple POJO router method that examines the object(s) in the list and return the appropriate channel name.

**EDIT**

Here's a boot app with a POJO router:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So41324522Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So41324522Application.class, args);
        MessageChannel channel = context.getBean("routingChannel", MessageChannel.class);
        channel.send(new GenericMessage<>(Collections.singletonList("Foo")));
        channel.send(new GenericMessage<>(Collections.singletonList(42)));
        context.close();
    }

    @Router(inputChannel = "routingChannel")
    public String route(List<Object> payload) {
        if (payload.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        if (payload.get(0) instanceof Integer) {
            return "integerChannel";
        }
        else {
            return "stringChannel";
        }
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "integerChannel")
    public void handleInt(List<Integer> in) {
        System.out.println("INT: " + in);
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "stringChannel")
    public void handleStr(List<String> in) {
        System.out.println("STR: " + in);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. For the syntax it's just the typo on this forum. Sorry for that.